# Pandas linear interpolate between different dataframes given values in each row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, interpolation

We have a few dataframes for the price of apples in different countries (say, China, USA, India etc) according to tenors, which look like the below. 
Taking China as example:

```
tenors = pd.Series(['1W', '1M', '1Y'])
apples_china = pd.Series([5.1, 6.2, 7.1])
days = pd.Series([7, 30, 365])
data = {'tenors': tenors, 
   'apples_china':  apples_china,
   'days' : days}
apples_china = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then we would have equivalent ones for the US (apples_usa), Europe (apples_eu) etc.

We then have a larger 'portfolio' dataframe that looks like:

```
country = pd.Series(['china', 'usa', 'europe',' china', 'china', 'india'])
days = pd.Series([12, 45, 99, 101, 102, 300 ])
portfolio = {'country': country, 
   'days' : days}
df_portfolio = pd.DataFrame(portfolio)
```

I would like to add a column:

```
df_portfolio['price']
```

that looks at the value in df_portfolio['country'] and, if it is 'china' for instance, takes the number of days (12 in row[0]) and linearly interpolates inside the apples_china dataframe. Thus it would be a value between 5.1 and 6.2 on row[0], a value between 6.2 and 7.1 on row[3] and so forth.

For row[1], it would be looking inside the analogous apples_usa dataframe etc.

What i tried is:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
test = interp1d(apples_china['apples_china'], apples_china['days']) #arrays Y and X 
df_portfolio['price'] = np.where(df_portfolio['country']=='china', test(df_portfolio['days']), 0)
```

But it returned a `ValueError` with the x range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with a couple of choices is suitable for `numpy.where` treatment.

However, for a scalable solution involving many countries, a dictionary may be more useful. Below I lay out the necessary steps:

**Step 1**

Create a dictionary mapping country to your country-specific data.

```
country_map = {'china': apples_china.sort_values('days')}
```

Note that we need to ensure that your country dataframes are sorted by `days` to ensure that `np.interp` in Step 2 works as required.

**Step 2**

Define a custom function which takes a row of data from your portfolio dataframe, and also the mapping dictionary from Step 1, then use `np.interp` to perform the mapping. You can use a `try` / `except` clause to catch instances where a country does not exist in your dictionary.

```
def interpolator(row, mapper):
    days = row['days']
    country = row['country']
    try:
        return np.interp(days, mapper[country]['days'].values,
                         mapper[country]['apples_china'].values)
    except KeyError:
        return np.nan
```

**Step 3**

Use `pd.DataFrame.apply` to apply the function from Step 2 by row.

```
df_portfolio['price'] = df_portfolio.apply(interpolator, mapper=country_map, axis=1)
```

**Result**

```
print(df_portfolio)

  country  days     price
0   china    12  5.339130
1     usa    45       NaN
2  europe    99       NaN
3   china   101  6.390746
4   china   102  6.393433
5   india   300       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you jpp.  One small amendment I think is in the interpolator function,  np.interp(days, mapper[country][days], mapper[country].iloc[:, 0].values instead of mapper[country]['apples_china'].values once we add more countries.